# A question about simple Keras and Tensorflow code performance

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I wrote simple Sin function predictors using Keras and Tensorflow with LSTM, but found the performance of Keras code is much slower which runs about 5 min while Tensorflow code runs the model just in 20 seconds. Moreover, the Keras prediction performance is less precide as Keras one. Could anyone help me find the code difference between the 2 model?

I hacked the code online and intend to train the model with the same hyper parameters. But the performance is not as expected. Tried searching many materials online, but found no reasons.

Keras Code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import time
from tqdm._tqdm_notebook import tqdm_notebook
import pickle
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, CSVLogger
from keras import optimizers
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

stime = time.time()
BATCH_SIZE = 20
TIME_STEPS = 10
LN = 410
DIFF = 2
OUTPUT_PATH = '/Users/xiachang/Documents/RNN/test_outputs'
SCALER_COL_IDX = 0

params = {
    "batch_size": BATCH_SIZE,  # 20<16<10, 25 was a bust
    "epochs": 500,
    "lr": 0.00010000,
    "time_steps": TIME_STEPS
}

TRAINING_EXAMPLES = 10000
TESTING_EXAMPLES = 1000
SAMPLE_GAP = 0.01
HIDDEN_UNITS = 20

# data = np.array([[i * (DIFF)] for i in range(LN)])
#
# min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
# data = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data)


def generate_data(seq):
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(seq) - TIME_STEPS):
        X.append([[e] for e in seq[i: i + TIME_STEPS]])
        y.append([seq[i + TIME_STEPS]])
    return np.array(X, dtype=np.float32), np.array(y, dtype=np.float32)


test_start = (TRAINING_EXAMPLES + TIME_STEPS) * SAMPLE_GAP + 1
test_end = test_start + (TESTING_EXAMPLES + TIME_STEPS) * SAMPLE_GAP + 1
train_X, train_y = generate_data(np.sin(np.linspace(
    0, test_start, TRAINING_EXAMPLES + TIME_STEPS, dtype=np.float32)))
test_X, test_y = generate_data(np.sin(np.linspace(
    test_start, test_end, TESTING_EXAMPLES + TIME_STEPS, dtype=np.float32)))

x_val, x_test = np.split(test_X, 2)
y_val, y_test = np.split(test_y, 2)


def print_time(text, stime):
    seconds = (time.time()-stime)
    print(text, seconds//60,"minutes : ",np.round(seconds%60),"seconds")


def create_model():
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_UNITS, return_sequences=True))
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_UNITS, return_sequences=True))
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_UNITS))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation=None))
    lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.1))
    return lstm_model


model = create_model()

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=30, min_delta=0.0001)

mcp = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH,
                      "best_model.h5"), monitor='val_loss', verbose=1,
                      save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='min', period=1)

# Not used here. But leaving it here as a reminder for future
r_lr_plat = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=30,
                              verbose=0, mode='auto', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)

csv_logger = CSVLogger(os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, 'training_log_' + time.ctime().replace(" ","_") + '.log'), append=True)

history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=params["epochs"], verbose=2, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    shuffle=False, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks=[es, mcp, csv_logger])

print("saving model...")
pickle.dump(model, open("test_outputs/lstm_model", "wb"))

# Visualize the training data
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig(os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, 'train_vis_BS_'+str(BATCH_SIZE)+"_"+time.ctime()+'.png'))

# load the saved best model from above
saved_model = load_model(os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, 'best_model.h5')) # , "lstm_best_7-3-19_12AM",
print(saved_model)

y_pred = saved_model.predict(x_test, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
y_pred = y_pred.flatten()
y_test_t = y_test
error = mean_squared_error(y_test_t, y_pred)
print("Error is", error, y_pred.shape, y_test_t.shape)
print(y_pred[0:15])
print(y_test_t[0:15])
y_pred_org = y_pred
y_test_t_org = y_test_t
print(y_pred_org[0:15])
print(y_test_t_org[0:15])

# Visualize the prediction
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(y_pred_org)
plt.plot(y_test_t_org)
plt.title('Prediction vs Real Value')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.legend(['Prediction', 'Real'], loc='upper left')
# plt.show()
plt.savefig(os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, 'pred_vs_real_BS'+str(BATCH_SIZE)+"_"+time.ctime()+'.png'))
print_time("program completed ", stime)
```

Tensorflow code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


NUM_EPOCH = 1000
HIDDEN_SIZE = 30
NUM_LAYERS = 2
TIMESTEPS = 10
TRAINING_STEPS = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 20
TRAINING_EXAMPLES = 10000
TESTING_EXAMPLES = 1000
SAMPLE_GAP = 0.01


def generate_data(seq):
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(seq) - TIMESTEPS):
        X.append([seq[i: i + TIMESTEPS]])
        y.append([seq[i + TIMESTEPS]])
    return np.array(X, dtype=np.float32), np.array(y, dtype=np.float32)


def lstm_model(X, y, is_training):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(HIDDEN_SIZE) for _ in range(NUM_LAYERS)])
    outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
    output = outputs[:, -1, :]
    predictions = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(output, 1, activation_fn=None)
    if not is_training:
        return predictions, None, None
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=predictions)
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss, tf.train.get_global_step(), optimizer='Adagrad', learning_rate=0.1)
    return predictions, loss, train_op


def train(sess, train_X, train_Y):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_X, train_Y))
    ds = ds.repeat().shuffle(1000).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    X, y = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    losses = np.array([])

    with tf.variable_scope('model'):
        predictions, loss, train_op = lstm_model(X, y, True)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(TRAINING_STEPS):
        _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss])
        losses = np.append(losses, l)
        if i % NUM_EPOCH == 0:
            print('train step: ' + str(i) + ', loss: ' + str(l))

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(losses, label='loss')
    plt.legend()
    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig('./test_outputs/loss.png')


def run_eval(sess, test_X, test_y):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_X, test_y))
    ds = ds.batch(1)
    X, y = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    with tf.variable_scope('model', reuse=True):
        prediction, _, _ = lstm_model(X, [0, 0], False)
    predictions = []
    labels = []
    for i in range(int(TESTING_EXAMPLES / 2)):
        p, l = sess.run([prediction, y])
        predictions.append(p)
        labels.append(l)

    predictions = np.array(predictions).squeeze()
    labels = np.array(labels).squeeze()
    rmse = np.sqrt(((predictions - labels) ** 2).mean(axis=0))
    print('Mean Square Error is: %f' % rmse)

    plt.figure()
    print(predictions[:15])
    print(labels[:15])
    plt.plot(predictions, label='predictions')
    plt.plot(labels, label='real_val')
    plt.legend()
    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig('./test_outputs/test.png')


test_start = (TRAINING_EXAMPLES + TIMESTEPS) * SAMPLE_GAP + 1
test_end = test_start + (TESTING_EXAMPLES + TIMESTEPS) * SAMPLE_GAP + 1
train_X, train_y = generate_data(np.sin(np.linspace(
    0, test_start, TRAINING_EXAMPLES + TIMESTEPS, dtype=np.float32)))
test_X, test_y = generate_data(np.sin(np.linspace(
    test_start, test_end, TESTING_EXAMPLES + TIMESTEPS, dtype=np.float32)))

x_val, test_X = np.split(test_X, 2)
y_val, test_y = np.split(test_y, 2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    train(sess, train_X, train_y)
    run_eval(sess, test_X, test_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe should try to use `CuDNNLSTM` instead of `LSTM`. They are CUDA accelerated.

Fast LSTM implementation with [CuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn).

See here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py#L328

Answer (score 0):

1. Your model structure is not same, first has `3` layers of `LSTM`, other has `2`.
2. Tensorflow data API is highly optimized, It preparing the data-set, without wasting any resources.

Note that: You can even more accelerate the training in tensorflow using parallelization in `dynamic_rnn` cell. [check out this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn).

Comment: The LSTM code was 2 layers before and it took also much much longer than the tensorflow code. Are the 2 blocks of code are exactly the same except the number of layers? I am kind of confused why the performance difference is such large.